# How to make a package remove another (older) package?

Tags: debian, packaging

I wrote a C++ program and then created a package. Every thing went normally with the installing and what not. But now I have another version of the program, an update. Is there a way to create a package with this new version that deletes the old one, or do I have to remove the old version manually and then install the new version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare a Replaces relationship with your previous version, take a look [here](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#s-replaces)

Comment: Exactly what I has locking for! Thank you very must!